# How to plot regression lines for multiple y

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I am trying to plot regression lines for my 3 Y variable and my 1 x variable.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

Sika_deer<-read.csv("C:/Users/Lau/Desktop/Sikadeer.csv", sep = ";",header = T)

Plot<-ggplot(Sika_deer, aes(x=Year)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=Females, color="Females")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=Young, color="Youngs")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=Males, color="Males")
             )+ facet_wrap(~District, scales = ("free_y"))+
  labs(x = "Number of culled animals", y = "Year)")
```

I tried using geom_smooth but I keep on receiving the error:`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
Errore: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: y

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Thank you all for the attention and help!

p.s sorry if I made some mistakes posting my question, it's my first time asking for help on an online platform.

[This is my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHhtt.png)

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to reshape your data into long format to avoid the need for repeated calls to `geom_point` and `geom_smooth`, but the following should work for you:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

Sika_deer <- read.csv("C:/Users/Lau/Desktop/Sikadeer.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE)

Plot <- ggplot(Sika_deer, aes(x = Year)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Females, color = "Females")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Young, color = "Youngs")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Males, color = "Males")) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = Females, color = "Females"), se = FALSE) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y = Young, color = "Youngs"), se = FALSE) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y = Males, color = "Males"), se = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~District, scales = ("free_y")) +
  labs(x = "Number of culled animals", y = "Year)")
```

If this does not work for you, please edit your question to include a sample of your data by typing `dput(Sika_deer)` into the console and pasting the result into your question.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I managed to have the plot I wanted, even though I received this message: geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50).

thanks again :)

Comment: This is just a message to make explicit the default method for fitting a line to the data in case that's not what you wanted. If you didn't want a loess, you can modify the method/formula in the `geom_smooth` call. For more info see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html.

Answer (score 0):

I agree about transforming to long data before trying this plot, then you can pass the color variable into `aes` at the top and the subsequent layers will just inherit it. Since I don't have your data to confirm an answer, I'm showing an example with the `iris` dataset but it will be the same with yours.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Species, Sepal.Length), names_to = "attribute") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = value, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(facets = "attribute",  scales = "free_y")
```

[image: sample_plot]

With your data I think you could try:

```
Sika_deer %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(District, year), names_to = "category") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, color = category)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(facets = "District", scales = "free_y") +
  labs(x = "Number of culled animals", y = "Year)")
```

But if you share the output of `dput(Sika_deer)` in your question, we can be sure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, trying with your code I receive the message: `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'.

I tried with dput(Sika_deer) but the output was very long to copy. My database is made by 5 columns: Year, District, N of female culled, N of males culled, N of young culled.

I want to see how the number of deer culled in the single district changed through the years

Comment: Can you subset to just 2 or 3 of the districts to make it small enough for sharing?